# SELECT query time to read from 170 partitions in a postgresql database

Tags: database, postgresql

I am planning to have a hourly partition to store 1 week data. Each partition will have 25 million records(1 million groups produce 25 records each).  I am able to run a SELECT query for a group around 3 to 4 partitions in 30 milli seconds.

**My ask is:**
It's taking a lot of time to create these many partitions with data. So, I am looking for experts knowledge to predict, how much time it takes to query 170 partitions? Will there be benefit because of parallel processing?

**Another question is:** It's expected around 4.2 billions of records in the table. I tried so far with 150 million records. It's going well. Can a POSTGRESQL database hold almost 4.2 million records?

Answer (score 1):

These kind of things are very hard to predict.

How much the creation of partitions will help depends heavily on the ability of the query optimizer to exclude partitions during planning of your queries. Look at the explain output for your queries to see if it is accessing all partitions or just a subset. If it can exclude many partitions this will keep queries fast.

To get the best possible results from parallel processing you will need to be on version 10. Partitions are not needed for parallel table scan just tables that are sufficiently large. See configuration parameter [min_parallel_table_scan_size](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-MIN-PARALLEL-TABLE-SCAN-SIZE)

For more information on parallel queries read [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/parallel-query.html).

Postgresql will have no trouble holding 4.2 billion rows. Number of rows per table is unlimited, table size is limited to 32 TB, but as you are partitioning you will not run into that there is also no limit on the database size. How usable it will be depends heavily on your hardware your queries and properly configuring postgresql.

Comment: Thank you Eelke for good explanation. If the user selects 1 week duration, my queries will hit all the partitions. I am more thinking about the performance, if query hits all 170 partitions. Though it's taking only 10 milli seconds for 1 partition, for 170 partitions whether it takes, 2 or 3 seconds?

Comment: 1 partition probably fits in memory which is why it is so fast 170 probably won't so performance will be way slower, could easily be hours. Do your queries need all data from all partitions or are they looking for specific rows? In that case indexes could help. If you don't filter on hour why did you choose to partition by hour? Could you show your table layout and give examples of typical queries?

Comment: My table schema has only 3 columns. group name, date and message. To see messages of a group, Website user needs to select a group name, which is mandatory and ask for messages of that group. He needs to select a time frame as well. But that time frame limit is only 1 week. My index is based on group id and timestamp. So, query can utilize index. My only issue is the timestamp can span entire 170 partitions. that is where, I am guessing the problem.

Comment: If there are enought groups it might be beneficial to also partition based on group but make sure you don't end up with too many partitions might be better to reduce your time based partitioning to per day in that case but you will have to experimentally determine what works best.

Comment: I have around 1 million groups. I can use group check sum and create around 100 partitions. Based on group checksum, I can insert into that partition. If i use this approach, my select queries will be faster as they just need to look into 1 partition. But delete queries will be slower. As we are keeping only 1 week data and on 8th day, we will be removing 1st day data, it means DELETE queries will hit all partitions. In my previous approach, DELETE queries will be hitting only few partitions and entire partition can be dropped.